# To make certain JS code more important than another (disappear on mouse out)

Tags: javascript, css

I know this might be silly but I would like to know if there is a way to realize.

Basically, I would like the dropdown-content element to 'KEEP DISPLAYING' even after 3 secs of mouse moving-out of the parental 'dropbtn' button or  element.

E.g. code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#dropbtn').hover(function() {
        $('.dropdown-content').css('display', 'block');
    }, function() {
        // on mouseout:
        setTimeout(function(){$('.dropdown-content').css('display', 'none');}, 3000);
    });
    $('.dropdown-content').hover(function(){
        $('.dropdown-content').css('display', 'block');
    },function(){
        $('.dropdown-content').css('display', 'none');
    })
});
```

Current issue is that setTimeout() function is overriding my desired way on this particular line of JS code:

```
$('.dropdown-content').css('display', 'block');
```

In another word, I want setTimeout() to be effective if and only if I set not my mouse cursor on 'dropdown-content' div.

Hope someone can help out :)

Comment: why do you need hover on the `.dropdown-content` if hovering on `#dropbtn` is showing `.dropdown-content`?

Comment: Hi. because I want .dropdown-content keep showing even if I move mouse out of #dropbtn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `hover`, you could use `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` to 'toggle' the `.dropdown-content`, except the delay of 3s on `mouseleave`:

```
$(function() {
    var dropdownTimeout = null;

    $('#dropbtn').mouseenter(function() {
        if(dropdownTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(dropdownTimeout);
            dropdownTimeout = null;
        }

        $('.dropdown-content').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('#dropbtn').mouseleave(function() {
        dropdownTimeout = setTimeout(function(){$('.dropdown-content').css('display', 'none');}, 3000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Anthony. How about if I would like the .dropdown-content keep displaying if I move out and back in within 3 seconds? Now it just disappear no mater what (once I move out for a sec)

Comment: @AndyYang I updated my answer to clear the timeout (if it exists) when you re-enter the `#dropbtn`